# Making Java DateFormat work for Shorter Values

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a program which reads a Dateformat from user once and for all at the beginning of program such as `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a`

Later on the program parses a File and use the Dateformat for all dates in the file. But recently I got a file, where 99% of the dates were `2014/09/01 12:00:04 AM` So The user can input `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a`.

However one date in that file is simply `2014/09/01` where the date format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a` fails.

Why can't `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a` format shorter dates such as in the format `yyyy/MM/dd`.

What I want is that the java program use the format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a` to parse the following two dates below:

1. 2014/09/01 12:00:04 AM
2. 2014/09/01

Thanks

Comment: How are you parsing the date ? Could you share the code ?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(USERs INPUT); // "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss a                           


Later on File is read

Buffer Reader Loop
     d1 = DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(current Date in files row); // could be "2014/09/01 12:00:04 AM" Or just "2014/09/01"

Variables Binded

End Loop

Comment: @NomanK Please edit your Question with more info such as example code rather than post as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two formats. Check the example below

```
DateFormat df = new DateFormat() {
      static final String FORMAT1 = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
      static final String FORMAT2 = "yyyy/MM/dd";
      final SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT1);
      final SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT2);

      @Override
      public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public Date parse(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
           if (source.length() - pos.getIndex() == FORMAT1.length())
                 return sdf1.parse(source, pos);
           return sdf2.parse(source, pos);
      }
};
System.out.println(df.parse("2014/09/01 12:00:04 AM"));
System.out.println(df.parse("2014/09/01"));
```

Comment: Thanks Thusitia, But The Format comes from the user and I cannot change the code at the moment for prod issues, I am searching for a generic DateFormat :)

Comment: in parse function you have declared two parameters in function one is String source and one is ParsePosition pos but when you are calling this function you are passing only one variable to the function?

Comment: @L-X that is an overloaded parse method. There are 2 parse methods

Comment: @NomanK hm then can you do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653223/how-to-parse-ambiguous-string-into-date

Comment: @NomanK This Answer gives you what you asked for, a DateFormat that handles either of two formats. If you are asking for a totally generic DateFormat to handle any and every possibility, that is impossible as you would have learned if you’d searched StackOverflow before posting.