# Is there a way to use a single date format string to parse two types of dates?

Tags: java, parsing, date, format

I'm using Java 1.6.  Is there a way to write a date format pattern that can parse both

```
2013-08-01
```

and

```
2013-08-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

?  I have tried the following

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

but it only matches the second, and dies with a ParseException on the first.  My parse code is:

```
final DateFormat defaultDateFormatObj = new SimpleDateFormat(classDateFormat);
final java.util.Date startDate = defaultDateFormatObj.parse(myDateString);
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897288/optional-parts-in-simpledateformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible to parse different formats in one DateFormatter

But, you can define one DateFormat for each one, and check for the presence of the "T" character, or the length of the date source, to decide which formatter to use.

I'd leave the try / catch to deal with really unparseable dates

Answer (score 1):

In short, I don't believe so.  I'd recommend using a try/catch with two different date formats (the second in the catch block).

The answer to this question should be helpful:

[How to parse dates in multiple formats using SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat)