# How to deal with 'optional' T in ISO-8601 timestamp in Java 8 / JSR 310 / threeten.org ?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

In Java 8 time / JSR 310 / threeten.org backport ...

**Q: How do I parse ISO-8601 timestamps with either a 'T' or a space ' ' between the date portion and the time portion?**

ISO-8601 format for timestamps specifies the literal 'T' to separate the date specification from the time specification:

```
2015-05-12T15:42:00.123
```

Many applications generate timestamps in this format with a space ' ' char instead of 'T'. References indicate that ISO-8601 allows this by *mutual agreement*.

```
2015-05-12 15:42:00.123
```

Because I am ingesting data from multiple sources I want to allow either the 'T' or the space ' '.

I observe that the pattern string allows one to specify optional components, but I do not see any way to specify a "choice" in a pattern string ...

**Q: Is there any way to make a "choose-exactly-one-of-the-following" in a JSR 310 pattern string?**

I was able to get this to work by constructing a DateTimeFormatter with two optional patterns:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    .optionalStart().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter();
```

Seeing optionalStart() and optionalEnd() led me to:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS][yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS]")
    .toFormatter();
```

However, I am not confident that this is the *correct* way to deal with this situation ...

**Q: What is the *best-practice* solution to handle multiple DateTime patterns?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to condense your three questions into one, for clarity's sake. Other than that, a very good question.

Comment: Just to note that java.time has no specific way to handle two options during parsing, such as " " or "T". This would be a reasonable enhancement to the API. The two solutions above will both successfully parse an empty string or a string with two date-times, so you need to check for those.

Comment: >  will both successfully parse an empty string or a string with two date-times
I was concerned about parsing 2 dates ... did not realize that an empty string would also pass. I will write some more tests. Thanks.

Comment: I found this SO most helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26132715/144599

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Cleanse Your Input Data

My own practice:

- Include the `T` by default.
- Clean the input data *before* calling [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) (or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)).

When accepting text from outside my own code, I *never* trust such external inputs. Heck, I don’t even trust my own *internal* inputs. I always put such data through a cleaner. As part of that cleaning I replace any SPACE character in any expected ISO 8601 string with a `T`.

```
String datetimeInput = input.replace( " ", "T" ) ;
```

I also make a habit of calling the [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library to trim [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) from the input string. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437933/how-to-properly-trim-whitespaces-from-a-string-in-java/1438156#1438156) for details.

And check for NULL, non-printing, and other inappropriate characters. Those non-printables make for nasty bugs.

Only after that do I call the date-time libraries ( [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ).

## Trap Parsing Exception

Also, you should use a [try-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) to trap for the parsing [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) to more gracefully handle when the date-time input string fails to meet your expectations.

- java.time: [DateTimeParseException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html)
- Joda-Time: [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html?is-external=true)

Comment: > I replace any SPACE character in any expected ISO 8601 string with a T
This is good advice and seems to be the cleanest way to handle this problem.