# Handling multiple formats in DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8, date-formatting, dateformatter

I am developing using Java 8 a function that must handle the conversion from `String` to `LocalDateTime` of the following dates:

- 2019-06-20 12:18:07.207 +0000 UTC
- 2019-06-20 12:18:07.20 +0000 UTC
- 2019-06-20 12:18:07.2 +0000 UTC
- 2019-06-20 12:18:07 +0000 UTC

The strings are produced from an external library that I cannot change.

Following the suggestions given in the SO answer [Optional parts in SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26132715/1173755), I tried using the optional formatting offered by the type `DateTimeFormatter`, using the characters `[` and `]`. I tried the following patterns:

- `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.S[S[S]]] Z z`
- `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.S[S][S]] Z z`

However, neither of them works.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build the pattern using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and reuse `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` and `ISO_LOCAL_TIME` constants:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(" ")
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .appendPattern("[ Z z]")
            .toFormatter();

    ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
```

The trick is that `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` handles the different number of digit used to represent milliseconds its own. From [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME) JavaDoc:

> This returns an immutable formatter capable of formatting and parsing the ISO-8601 extended local time format. The format consists of:
>   [..]
>   One to nine digits for the nano-of-second. As many digits will be output as required.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer did not respond to my question. The optional and variable part is the milliseconds' block, not the offset.

Comment: Doesn't ISO_LOCAL_TIME itself take care of that optional part of milliseconds? Try running the examples with this code.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Sorry. I added some useful information to your answer.

Comment: Thanks. You OK with ZonedDateTime, right? I think the requirement of having LocalDateTime in the question conflicts with zone specific text that needs to be parsed.

Comment: Don't worry. The problem was with the optional part.

Comment: Your `DateTimeFormatter` serves parsing to `ZonedDateTime` as well as `LocalDateTime` e.g. you can also use it as `LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-06-20 12:18:07.207 +0000 UTC", formatter);`

Answer (score 5):

I think it is better to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` for that purpose. For the optional parts just use one of the follwing methods :

1. [OptionalStart()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#optionalStart--) & [OptionalEnd()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#optionalEnd--)
2. Append your whole optional pattern with [appendOptional()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html)

Here is an example :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(""
    + "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z z]"
    + "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS Z z]"
    + "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S Z z]"
    + "[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z z]"
);
```

Also, you can create a dtf for each optional and append them with appendOptional() and the the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`

for example :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY,2)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR,2)
    .optionalEnd()
    .optionalStart()
    .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE,2)
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter();
```

This code is not tested but try to build your optional pattern each time in a start/end optional blocks.

Comment: In the first part of the answer, you cited the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, but you don't use it in the example. Can you modify the answer?

Comment: I added an brief example of how it may works with the builder, i didn't test it. Did the first way work?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my example that I use in one app that takes different formats
as you can see millisecond is optional and also 'Z' at end.

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
      .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
      .optionalStart()
      .appendLiteral('.')
      .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 1, 3, SignStyle.NORMAL)
      .optionalEnd()
      .optionalStart()
      .appendLiteral('Z')
      .optionalEnd()
      .toFormatter
```

appendPattern is static value, other at inside optional start and end, very simple to build such pattern ( if you know of course how to do that ;) )